# easy online LaTeX tests

Tags: online, examdesign

We use a commercial platform to place our technical tests online.  This automatically controls access, tracks metrics, and scores the multiple choice components.

It does not allow us to automatically upload questions from a LaTeX source, and requires a few workarounds beyond that.  For example, there is a 'LaTeX' button in the test question field, but not in the multiple-choice answer field; thus, I generate the answers in the test question, and cut/paste them into the answers when I need mathematics.  I have some diagrams as well.

Can anyone recommend a platform, commercial or otherwise, that makes it easier to upload from a LaTeX source?

Comment: Not sure if [WebQuiz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/webquiz) could help. It produces standalone quizzes but it is possible to customise the web pages it constructs. (Disclaimer: I wrote the package.)

Comment: thank you Andrew - I didn't know about WebQuiz, which looks very nice.  We're making some progress with our commercial platform, and I'm told that multiplying platforms isn't a good idea, so I'll push a bit further with it before playing properly with WebQuiz.  If you'd like to suggest WebQuiz as a formal answer, I'm happy to accept it.